# too many rerenders on using useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks

I am calling the `contacts`function from the main return. I don't see any error until here:

```
 const showContacts = React.useCallback(
    (data: UsersQueryHookResult) => {
      if (data) {
        return (
          <View style={styles.users}>
          </View>
        );
      }
    },
    [userData],
  );

  const contacts = () => {
    console.log('running');
    const { loading, error, data } = useUsersQuery({
      variables: {
        where: { id: 34 },
      },
    });
    console.log('DATA COMING', data);
    //setUserData(data);
    //console.log('contact name', data.users.nodes[0].userRelations[0].relatedUser.firstName);
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Container style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Item style={styles.addToWhitelist}>
          <Icon
            name="add"
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('AddContactTry')}
          />

          <Text style={styles.addToContactTitle}>Add contact</Text>
        </Item>
        <Text onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')}>Zurück</Text>
        <View style={{ width: moderateScale(350) }}>
          <Text>Keine Kontacte</Text>
        </View>
        {contacts()}
      </Container>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

Now I want to do some conditional rendering on the basis of the results from `contacts`. However, as soon as I uncomment `setUserData(data);` I get an error that too many re-renders. I don't get what I am doing wrong in `showUsers`to get this error.

Edit:

I tried this but it gives an invalid hook call error:

```
export const Whitelist: React.FunctionComponent = (props) => {

  const [userData, setUserData] = useState<UsersQueryHookResult>('');
 useEffect(() => {
    // Your function to fetch/get contacts
    const data = contacts();
    setUserData(data);
  }, [])

  const showContacts = React.useCallback(
    (data: UsersQueryHookResult) => {
      if (data) {
        return (
          <View style={styles.users}>
          </View>
        );
      }
    },
    [userData],
  );

  const contacts = () => {
    console.log('running');
    const { loading, error, data } = useUsersQuery({
      variables: {
        where: { id: 34 },
      },
    });
    console.log('DATA COMING', data);
    //setUserData(data);
  };



  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Container style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Item style={styles.addToWhitelist}>
          <Icon
            name="add"
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('AddContactTry')}
          />

          <Text style={styles.addToContactTitle}>Add contact</Text>
        </Item>
        <Text onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')}>Zurück</Text>
        {/* {contacts()} */}
      </Container>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

Comment: You're only supposed to set the state when an event occurs. If it's used directly in the render of your component, you're essentially creating an infinite re-render loop (since setting the state re-renders your component)

Comment: It's because `contact` is called in your render method and changes the state of the component. You should pass the contacts as props and only display them in the render method

Comment: @Baboo_ could you please provide an example in the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try to fetch `contacts` in componentDidMount method or useEffect (in your case with hooks) and store the result in a state with useState.

```
  const [contacts, setContacts] = React.useState(null);

  [...]

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Your function to fetch/get contacts
    const data = contacts();
    setContacts(data);
  }, [])

  [...]

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      [...]
      {contacts && contacts.map(contact => (<View>{contact.name}</View>)}
      [...]
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
```

hope it helps.

Comment: I tried your method (without what you're doing in the return for now). It gives me an invalid hook call error. Updated the code

Comment: Invalid hook call error on the useEffect? Do you have more details?